# Change an object in Database

Tags: c#, database

I am struggling with changing (actually adding) an attribute to an object which already exists in my database.

In my database, I have `Scenario` objects, and every `Scenario` object is linked with (one or more) `SceneWriter` objects. Now I would want to add one `SceneWriter` to my `Scenario` with a given `ScenarioID`.

Here is how I tried to do it:

```
string filmID = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        Scenario newScenario = new Scenario();
        foreach (Scenario scenario in scenarioes)
        {
            string thisID = scenario.filmID.ToString();
            if (thisID.Equals(filmID))
            {
                try
                {
                    // remove old scenario from DB
                    myDatabase.Scenario.Remove(scenario);
                    myDatabase.SaveChanges();


                    // add new scenario to DB, which now contains new scenewriter
                    newScenario = scenario;
                    scenario.SceneWriter.Add(newScenewriter); // this newScenewriter I fetched before
                    myDatabase.Scenario.Add(newScenario);
                    myDatabase.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ec)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ec.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

But it gives me an error while I try to delete this `Scenario` record from `myDatabase`, because it is linked with some other tables.

So what I would need, is to **not delete** any record, but to **change** it (just add this `SceneWriter`), preferably inside `myDatabase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just update the object

```
string filmID = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
Scenario newScenario = new Scenario();
foreach (Scenario scenario in myDatabase.Scenario
    .Where(scn => scn.filmID.ToString().Equals(filmId))
{
    scenario.SceneWriter.Add(newScenewriter);before
}

myDatabase.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @Whizzil I would convert the `filmID` variable to the same type as your `Scenario.filmID` that way you do not have to do a ToString()

Answer (score 1):

Just removed the code for removing the scenario and re adding it. it's absolutely redundant process.

```
    string filmID = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    Scenario newScenario = new Scenario();
    foreach (Scenario scenario in scenarioes)
    {
        string thisID = scenario.filmID.ToString();
        if (thisID.Equals(filmID))
        {
            try
            {
                scenario.SceneWriter.Add(newScenewriter);
                myDatabase.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ec)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ec.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```